# How to check whether a tuple exists in a Python list?

Tags: python, list, exists

I am new to Python, and I am trying to check whether a pair `[a,b]` exists in a list `l=[[a,b],[c,d],[d,e]]`. I searched many questions, but couldn't find precise solution. Please can someone tell me the right and shortest way of doing it?

when i run :

```
a=[['1','2'],['1','3']]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if [i,j] in a:
            print a
```

OUTPUT IS BLANK

how to achieve this then?

Comment: Your code works for me, output is `[[1,2], [1,3]]` as expected.

Comment: Ah, after you edited the code it's quite obvious, `[1,2]` != `['1','2']`.

Comment: sorry, i wanted this, i did'nt write properly

Comment: @bereal can you tell me how to do it now..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code does not work because `'1' != 1` and, consequently, `['1','2'] != [1,2]`
If you want it to work, try:

```
a=[['1','2'],['1','3']]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if [str(i), str(j)] in a: # Note str
            print a
```

(But using `in` or sets as already mentioned is better)

Answer (score 27):

Here is an example:

```
>>> [3, 4] in [[2, 1], [3, 4]]
True
```

If you need to do this a lot of times consider using a **`set`** though, because it has a much faster containment check.

Comment: i am using nested loops for `i in range(3):` and `for j in range(3)` and then trying for `[i,j] in a`....but its not identifying

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[['1','2'],['1','3']]
[[x,y] for x, y in a if [x,y]  == ['1','3']]
```

As per my understanding of you question, you were trying to find a specific list within another list.

for example ['1', '3'] within a.
using list comprehension you can solve this.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

In my interpreter (IPython 0.10, Python 2.7.2+) your code gives the correct output:

```
In [4]: a=[[1,2],[1,3]]

In [5]: for i in range(3):
   ...:         for j in range(3):
   ...:             if [i,j] in a:
   ...:                 print a
   ...: 
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

*(This should be a comment, but I can't leave them yet.)*

EDIT:

Turns out you had strings in the `a` list.
Then you need to convert your `int`s to `str` as well:

```
a=[['1','2'],['1','3']]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if [str(i), str(j)] in a:
            print a
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget that [a, b] is not [b, a] in python so you might want to order the 2 values in your tuples if you want to consider [A, B] and [B, A] is the same:

You might also want to use set(your_list) if your list is big and it has redundancy.

In your code example you are compaing integers and strings :

```
['1', '2'] # this is a 2-list of strings '1' and '2'
[1, 2] # this is a 2-list of integers 1 and 2
```