# Compare list of lists with a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to compare each list in the list of lists with the list based on the fact that each element is an interval and if that interval from "Listoflists" is included inside the interval from "List" we would get a True statement or else it would be a False one. And if possible, get in output a dataframe with True/False statement.

Here are the generated data :

```
List = [(4.960796557803424, 7.248503442196575), (5.038014752877868, 7.346085247122132), (5.103186780925054, 7.421613219074945), (5.105574436906216, 7.411525563093783), (5.09793832836004, 7.40086167163996), (5.117123344669599, 7.425176655330402), (5.140331981802099, 7.4544680181979), (5.153676999469211, 7.474623000530788), (5.169652452805959, 7.492747547194041), (5.176548183589987, 7.504451816410014), (5.179694590627988, 7.503005409372013), (5.186390607692675, 7.511009392307325), (5.187339125799644, 7.508960874200357), (5.189423235837134, 7.505376764162866), (5.199445384769695, 7.522654615230306), (5.1955279814463555, 7.512372018553645), (5.197146040939456, 7.511053959060543), (5.197860761030804, 7.516639238969197), (5.210950348383933, 7.529249651616069), (5.209023219591814, 7.5227767804081855), (5.197399815676738, 7.501300184323261), (5.195492268796732, 7.500807731203269), (5.210861199605485, 7.519838800394513), (5.204998445996691, 7.508901554003308), (5.20852003421463, 7.5121799657853705), (5.212252490189632, 7.524247509810367), (5.201234058771638, 7.500165941228362), (5.203652197491083, 7.503647802508917), (5.203165974373181, 7.504134025626819), (5.193959133355697, 7.490940866644302), (5.1988794553742315, 7.50032054462577), (5.197989848964307, 7.496210151035692), (5.1764459042422235, 7.466454095757777), (5.17883661246545, 7.472363387534549), (5.179113854294984, 7.475186145705015), (5.165933121850285, 7.456266878149714), (5.161950017421835, 7.454949982578165), (5.158510435609787, 7.456189564390212), (5.136973595450633, 7.425026404549368), (5.12549341260486, 7.416606587395141), (5.112957061397275, 7.397442938602726), (5.088003293233508, 7.365796706766493), (5.0680012406177966, 7.344398759382205), (5.027766228062783, 7.289433771937217), (4.98758418928086, 7.237615810719141), (4.941884579815628, 7.177315420184371), (4.8843399842923585, 7.101860015707642), (4.809069789199319, 7.0000302108006816), (4.712868404520053, 6.862731595479948), (4.594140983877125, 6.695059016122874)]
Listoflists = [[(5.624485901006036, 7.314114098993965), (5.411991077827618, 7.054208922172383), (5.236414671318958, 6.784685328681043)], [(5.624485901006036, 7.314114098993965), (5.411991077827618, 7.054208922172383), (5.236414671318958, 6.784685328681043)], [(5.624485901006036, 7.314114098993965), (5.411991077827618, 7.054208922172383), (5.236414671318958, 6.784685328681043)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.537573221519728, 7.167826778480273), (5.5812641275580726, 7.228535872441927), (5.538628919468101, 7.1545710805319), (5.452498368454096, 7.082601631545904), (5.614454290015469, 7.294645709984532), (5.6133091333567045, 7.294990866643296), (5.654112609506859, 7.3263873904931405), (5.5870048201935125, 7.264595179806489), (5.630825712428621, 7.322874287571381), (5.633694432612272, 7.320705567387727), (5.666478901946156, 7.370621098053843), (4.988901956502318, 6.487398043497683)], [(5.486756512505686, 7.108943487494315), (5.502462012633316, 7.109137987366683)], [(5.486756512505686, 7.108943487494315), (5.502462012633316, 7.109137987366683)], [(5.6211930530698115, 7.284606946930188), (5.538370684448803, 7.184029315551197), (5.400211474921432, 6.992988525078569)], [(5.6211930530698115, 7.284606946930188), (5.538370684448803, 7.184029315551197), (5.400211474921432, 6.992988525078569)], [(5.6211930530698115, 7.284606946930188), (5.538370684448803, 7.184029315551197), (5.400211474921432, 6.992988525078569)], [(5.625321394155952, 7.2834786058440475), (5.543237464503713, 7.167062535496287), (5.609005028975223, 7.2505949710247775), (5.66266675738864, 7.3353332426113615), (5.593157996296727, 7.243842003703273), (5.6916504629293465, 7.368249537070654), (5.082570543334951, 6.597429456665049)], [(5.625321394155952, 7.2834786058440475), (5.543237464503713, 7.167062535496287), (5.609005028975223, 7.2505949710247775), (5.66266675738864, 7.3353332426113615), (5.593157996296727, 7.243842003703273), (5.6916504629293465, 7.368249537070654), (5.082570543334951, 6.597429456665049)], [(5.625321394155952, 7.2834786058440475), (5.543237464503713, 7.167062535496287), (5.609005028975223, 7.2505949710247775), (5.66266675738864, 7.3353332426113615), (5.593157996296727, 7.243842003703273), (5.6916504629293465, 7.368249537070654), (5.082570543334951, 6.597429456665049)], [(5.625321394155952, 7.2834786058440475), (5.543237464503713, 7.167062535496287), (5.609005028975223, 7.2505949710247775), (5.66266675738864, 7.3353332426113615), (5.593157996296727, 7.243842003703273), (5.6916504629293465, 7.368249537070654), (5.082570543334951, 6.597429456665049)], [(5.625321394155952, 7.2834786058440475), (5.543237464503713, 7.167062535496287), (5.609005028975223, 7.2505949710247775), (5.66266675738864, 7.3353332426113615), (5.593157996296727, 7.243842003703273), (5.6916504629293465, 7.368249537070654), (5.082570543334951, 6.597429456665049)], [(5.625321394155952, 7.2834786058440475), (5.543237464503713, 7.167062535496287), (5.609005028975223, 7.2505949710247775), (5.66266675738864, 7.3353332426113615), (5.593157996296727, 7.243842003703273), (5.6916504629293465, 7.368249537070654), (5.082570543334951, 6.597429456665049)], [(5.625321394155952, 7.2834786058440475), (5.543237464503713, 7.167062535496287), (5.609005028975223, 7.2505949710247775), (5.66266675738864, 7.3353332426113615), (5.593157996296727, 7.243842003703273), (5.6916504629293465, 7.368249537070654), (5.082570543334951, 6.597429456665049)], [(5.53613079846842, 7.159969201531581), (5.6371294512269285, 7.300970548773072), (5.568992317062811, 7.190907682937189), (5.774366988264341, 7.490033011735659), (5.689328310328547, 7.371471689671454), (5.548454703339994, 7.200745296660006), (5.607135343983764, 7.237664656016236)], [(5.53613079846842, 7.159969201531581), (5.6371294512269285, 7.300970548773072), (5.568992317062811, 7.190907682937189), (5.774366988264341, 7.490033011735659), (5.689328310328547, 7.371471689671454), (5.548454703339994, 7.200745296660006), (5.607135343983764, 7.237664656016236)], [(5.53613079846842, 7.159969201531581), (5.6371294512269285, 7.300970548773072), (5.568992317062811, 7.190907682937189), (5.774366988264341, 7.490033011735659), (5.689328310328547, 7.371471689671454), (5.548454703339994, 7.200745296660006), (5.607135343983764, 7.237664656016236)], [(5.53613079846842, 7.159969201531581), (5.6371294512269285, 7.300970548773072), (5.568992317062811, 7.190907682937189), (5.774366988264341, 7.490033011735659), (5.689328310328547, 7.371471689671454), (5.548454703339994, 7.200745296660006), (5.607135343983764, 7.237664656016236)], [(5.53613079846842, 7.159969201531581), (5.6371294512269285, 7.300970548773072), (5.568992317062811, 7.190907682937189), (5.774366988264341, 7.490033011735659), (5.689328310328547, 7.371471689671454), (5.548454703339994, 7.200745296660006), (5.607135343983764, 7.237664656016236)], [(5.53613079846842, 7.159969201531581), (5.6371294512269285, 7.300970548773072), (5.568992317062811, 7.190907682937189), (5.774366988264341, 7.490033011735659), (5.689328310328547, 7.371471689671454), (5.548454703339994, 7.200745296660006), (5.607135343983764, 7.237664656016236)], [(5.53613079846842, 7.159969201531581), (5.6371294512269285, 7.300970548773072), (5.568992317062811, 7.190907682937189), (5.774366988264341, 7.490033011735659), (5.689328310328547, 7.371471689671454), (5.548454703339994, 7.200745296660006), (5.607135343983764, 7.237664656016236)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)], [(5.366898199538092, 6.952401800461908), (5.39976840137702, 6.999131598622981), (5.347062317281391, 6.973037682718609), (5.500327401989365, 7.163472598010635), (5.348496716709206, 6.954703283290795), (5.459572139235642, 7.0954278607643575), (5.270226488204126, 6.846073511795873), (5.2754687250413435, 6.893431274958657), (5.477930742790426, 7.105069257209572), (4.983069161432187, 6.521030838567814), (4.963886091621905, 6.476613908378095), (4.983402688518933, 6.498897311481065), (5.171912572830255, 6.7390874271697445), (5.011399738614732, 6.552000261385268), (5.111506124019241, 6.658993875980759), (5.112209948356012, 6.633190051643988)]]
```

Example to describe it clearly (it's not a code it's just to have a clear view):

```
We take the first list of lists from the "Listoflists" : [(5.624485901006036, 7.314114098993965), (5.411991077827618, 7.054208922172383), (5.236414671318958, 6.784685328681043)]
We compare each interval with all the intervals from the "List".

If (5.624485901006036, 7.314114098993965) (which is the first element from "Listoflists") is in the intervals from "List" we will get a True statement, Else we will have a False one.
```

Comment: Hi Hamid, can please simply your dataset. it is enormous. What format is it in? is it a uniform 2D array? It's hard to tell in this state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a tuple exists in a Python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654523/how-to-check-whether-a-tuple-exists-in-a-python-list)

Comment: Hello Freddy, no it doesn't because I want to compare a complete interval not just a value. If for example i have (1, 3) and i want to compare it to (0, 4) then the answer is True because it is included in that interval.

Comment: Are you asking if any value in `ListOfLists` is a subset of any interval in `List`?  And are all values in these tuples sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking if each element in `ListofLists` is a subset of any tuple in `List`

```
y = []
for i in Listoflists:
    for j in i:
        for ii in List:
            # Sort each tuple. Remove this if they are already sorted
            sorta = sorted(j)
            sortb = sorted(ii)
            y.append(sorta[0] >= sortb[0] and sorta[1] <= sortb[1])
```

```
>>> y[0:5]
[False, True, True, True, True]
```

This goes with the rationale that a subset of `[0,1]` can be `[0,1]` (the same set). If you want it to not include the same set, remove the `=` from the inequalities.

---

And try not to name your variables after classes (`List`) as it can cause unexpected errors

Comment: It's all False because you are not considering it as an interval. I gave you an small example in your first comment, would you please check it and see if you understood what i need for the code to consider. Thank you Freddy

Comment: Thank you it worked ! Have a great day Freddy

Comment: No worries Hamid, you too

Answer (score 0):

You need to try and make your problems statement simpler and clearer. Also its kind of taboo to start variable names with a capital letter (like `List` and `ListOfLists`). You can better write: `lst` (becasue list is taken) and `list_of_lists`.

From what i understand, you are looking for this:

```
lst  = [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
data = [[(1, 2), (8, 5), (7, 3)], [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]]

# check if lst is present in data
if lst in data:
    # do something if the lst was found in data (ListOfLists)
    print("yay")
else:
    # do something if the lst was not found in data
    print("nay")
```

If you are trying to find if one of these: (1, 5) tuples in your List is present in one if the lists in your ListOfLists. You can do the following:

```
lst  = [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
data = [[(1, 2), (8, 5), (7, 3)], [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]]

for el in data:
    for tpl in lst:
        if tpl in el:
            # you found that (2, 5) is in data[1]
            print("yay")
```

EDIT: for interval checking

```
lst  = [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
data = [[(1, 2), (8, 5), (7, 3)], [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]]

# for intervals in lst
for tpl in lst:

    # go over list of intervals
    for i, interval_list in enumerate(data):
        for interval in interval_list:
            # check if between interval (inclusive)
            if tpl[0] >= interval[0] and tpl[1] <= interval[1]:
                print(tpl, 'fits in interval located in list', i)
                print('the interval:', interval)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both of the solutions you've proposed are not resolving my problem because i'm talking about intervals not integers. If for example i have (1, 3) and i want to compare it to (0, 4) then the answer is True because it is included in that interval.

Comment: Ah okay, understood. Let me add a code snippet for that.

Comment: You need to sort your test data, as `(8, 5)` (and others) is not a valid set / interval

Comment: Freddy i would say thats another problem for the person asking the question. Yes he needs to remove the invalid intervals, but he is not asking for that. Invalid intervals will just be skipped with the solution I gave. Which is fine for his problem.

Comment: Yeah it really does fall down to the question. OP needs to specify what to do here